# setting different cron params dynamically in java spring @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

How can I set a my own variable here - "${cron.expression}"  ?

This param want final constant. I want to change the values dynamically  when program is runing. For example I need to set the `LocalDate` when this element should execute.

Please write an example , how I can do it.

```
@Service
    public class ScheduledService {
        @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression}")
        public void demoServiceMethod() {
            //do something 
        }

    }
```

Comment: You cant use the @Scheduled annotation to do this. You have to create your own TaskExecutor

Comment: Here is an example, hope this helps
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler

Comment: I solved this problem with that way...
I will use @Scheduled to check the date from the database. And if today - date that I need - do something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with that way: 
I will use @Scheduled to check the date from the database. 
And if today - date that I need - do something... Like that:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 86_400_000)// One day
    public void demoServiceMethod() {
if(Localdate.now().isEqual(//date that I need)){
//do something
   }
        //do something everyday
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not set annotation parameters dynamically. you can do it programmatically, like below.

```
class Scheduler implements Runnable {
    public Scheduler(TaskScheduler scheduler, String timezone, String cron) {
        scheduler.schedule(this, new CronTrigger(cron, TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone)));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //code goes here
    }
}
```